# What is a Tromboning arrival procedure?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, instrument-flight-rules, approach

I only know that Tromboning is a RNAV arrival procedure which has the trombone shape, and it's an application of CDO (Continuous Descent Operation) along with Point Merge Procedure. Can you give me some documents related to this procedure, and some example of the airport that have been using this procedure?

Answer (score 5):

Here’s an example of a ‘Trombone’-type arrival into Frankfurt International.

[image]

This style of approach works very well for large airports, which have multiple parallel runways for landing e.g. Hartsfield Jackson in Atlanta, LAX, etc.  note Hal, the approach involves downwind legs parallel to the runway that the traffic will be landing on a multiple points along the way, which controllers can sequence large amounts of traffic onto final. This gives a plan view the approach, the appearance of a trombone handle, hence the name. Functionally this kind of instrument approach works similar to a VFR break and landing pattern used by the military for recovering large numbers of aircraft elements and sections quickly, albeit in a much greater volume of space and does not rely on aggressive visual breaks to separate traffic.